# Cannot unmount/remove 'Linux' drive from Windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive, mount, unmount

System: Windows 10, up to date

I have a mysterious drive/folder which appears mounted on Windows 10, called simply 'Linux', which I cannot unmount or otherwise get rid of. It's empty, and there do not seem to be any options for its removal. For some context, while I am not 100% sure when it first appeared, I suspect that it happened when I tried to connect an old Kindle to my PC a while back. I could not connect the Kindle for some reason (I assumed because it was so old), and it's my belief that this 'Linux' drive was the Kindle, mounted incorrectly, or in an incomplete state to the OS. However, I just want to get rid of it, and I don't like how it seems to be untouchable. I have of course searched for a solution to this, but have not found any which deal with this particular scenario. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Here are some screenshots.

The 'drive' in question, it's always just there.

[image]

The context menu when right-clicking on it, no options to eject/unmount etc.

[image]

It seemingly has no content

[image]

Clicking properties from the context menu, I see an error

[image]

Comment: @GeraldSchneider While the link above to the superuser post did not clearly/directly answer this question, it did help me to do a Google search which allowed me to solve it. So thank you for that. I simply had to go into 'Apps and Features' > 'Programs & Features' > uncheck 'Windows Subsystem for Linux', and restart the system. I had no idea this Linux icon was related to that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, I simply had to go into 'Apps and Features' > 'Programs & Features', and uncheck 'Windows Subsystem for Linux'. Then I restarted the system. This got rid of the Linux drive appearing in explorer.

Answer (score 0):

`regedit` -> `{B2B4A4D1-2754-4140-A2EB-9A76D9D7CDC6}`, i.e. one of these:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{B2B4A4D1-2754-4140-A2EB-9A76D9D7CDC6}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{B2B4A4D1-2754-4140-A2EB-9A76D9D7CDC6}
```

Then define

```
System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree := 0
```

[image]